# Validation in ASPXUpload Control in Devexpress + XPO

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net

I have added ASPXUploadControl to save the Image File.

I want to apply Validation (Required Field Validation) on this control.. 
but i dont find ValidationSetting Tag in this Control

```
<asp:FileUpload runat="server" ID="fuAttachment" CssClass="mediumResolution required" Width="100%" />
```

How can i achieve this task?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Possibly, this control is not intended for this validation type. Please check whether the information provided in these threads helps you:

[ASPxUploadControl - How to validate a file before uploading it](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/p/B195766.aspx)

[file type validation ASPxUploadControl](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/p/Q312398.aspx)